# Error displays on system start up - Server is already active for display 0

Tags: server, xorg, login, lightdm

I honestly have no idea why, but when i upgraded mint from version 16 to 17 some moons ago I got the following error:

Fatal server error:
    Server is already active for display 0
        If this server is no longer running, remove /temp/.X0-lock and start again

What happens is

```
Turn on machine
Wait until login screen is displayed
error will appear on screen, `Yes|No` do you want to display the log 
Click `No`, taken back to login screen. 
Continue with login as normal
```

So this isn't stopping me functioning, but it is annoying to have for so long.

[image]

Comment: I fixed this by doing a clean install.